# SSRS alignment issue when exporting to PDF and Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

> this is the ssrs report image see the red boxes it is properly aligned

[SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLBJx.png)

> but when i am exporting to PDF or excel alignment issue are coming
>   pdf image 
>   [SSRS exported to PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdLK1.png)

Comment: You are right and it is very annoying :(

Comment: any solution Salmon ?

Comment: Best I could get was putting the report in a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this many times. Most of the time its manually adjusting the padding of the header and the taxlib item itself. You will just have to export and check in pdf. No earier way.